# React time ago not getting date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-timeago package, i just need to get the data from a parent component by props, when i put the data in the date prop of TimeAgo i get nothing.

**props.date** is not getting the data in the **TimeAgo** component, i have tried **this.props.date** but in vain. the code below is in the same component

```
// this returns for ex 'Published 2 days ago'
<div>Published {props.date}</div>
// this returns only 'Published'
<div>Published <TimeAgo date={props.date} formatter={formatter}/></div>
```

Comment: In what format are you getting the date from the parent component? Could you try `console` logging and see the result?

Comment: {props.date} return 2 days ago, but when i put {props.date} inside TimeAgo's date={} it returns nothing in the same component

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/nmn/react-timeago#date-required), ```date``` property required "Date Object, A UTC date-string or number of milliseconds" instead of "2 days ago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `props.date` return a literal string that cannot be directly converted into a date object or date string, firstly you'll need to convert it into a standard format and then pass it to the `props`. Before the `return` block add this code.

```
var calDate = stringToDate()

function stringToDate(){
 let cDate = new Date();
cDate.setDate(cDate.getDate() - parseInt(props.date)); //Get the integer part of X days ago, e.g return the integer 2 from 2 days ago and then subtract 2 days from current date.
//console.log(calDate.toString());
return cDate
}
```

Update the value passed to prop to the value we calculated above.

```
// this returns for ex 'Published 2 days ago'
<div>Published {props.date}</div>
// this returns only 'Published'
<div>Published <TimeAgo date={calDate} formatter={formatter}/></div>
```